# Redundant boundary condition of a $1$st order ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

Consider the following $1$st order eigen ODE system of 2 components $(\alpha,\beta)(x)$ defined for $x\in[0,L]$
$$
F_{l+1}\beta+m\alpha=\lambda\alpha\\
F_{-l}\alpha-m\beta=\lambda\beta
$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, $l$ is integer, $m(0)$ is finite and $m(L)\rightarrow\infty$, and $F_k=-i(\frac{d}{dx}+\frac{k}{x})$.

Since it is just $1$st order, I thought only 2 boundary conditions (b.c.) are necessary, which can be most easily taken as $(\alpha,\beta)(L)=0$ since $m(L)$ diverges. **So one doesn't need or just shouldn't involve  b.c. at $x=0$?**

However, on the other hand, if I do the very simple asymptotic analysis at $x\rightarrow0$ for these equations, I find that 
$$
l\neq0,-1\qquad (\alpha,\beta)(0)=0\\
l=-1\qquad (\alpha,\beta')(0)=0
$$
with $l=0$ similar to $l=-1$. What I did is basically just noting that, when $k\neq0$, any component acted by $F_k$ is $0$ at $x=0$. And using this, we notice the other component's derivative vanishes. **It seems that b.c. at $x=0$ is natural as well.**

How to reconcile these two considerations? Where am I wrong? And if $m(x)$ is always finite and smooth enough, is the asymptotic analysis the correct b.c.?

Comment: It seems that both of your boundaries ($x=0$ and $x=L$) are [regular singular points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point). To specify a boundary condition at a singular point, you cannot simply use the value of the function or its derivative (they may be automatically zero, or even divergent, for every solution, as you noticed). What you need to do is impose conditions on the coefficients of the leading asymptotic terms for the independent solutions (cf. the [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thank you. What if $L$ is at $+\infty$? Will it be different?

Comment: you can always use the change of variables $y=1/x$ to bring $x=\infty$ to $y=0$. Then the asymptotic analysis is the same.